# How to efficiently retrieve groupby objects as a function of a pd.Series

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have two dataframes: main_df (`cols=['Technology', 'Condition1', Condition2']`) and database_df (`cols=['Technology', 'Values1', 'Values2'])`.

I have grouped the database_df depending on the `Technology` column:

`grouped = database_df.groupby(['Technology'])`

Now, what I would like to do is to get the `pd.series` `main_df['Technology']` in main_df, for every row retrieve the relevant group, filter according to some conditions depending on some other column values of main_df and return the first row's `['Character']` column (of the database_df) that fulfills the conditions.

I.e. I would like to do something like:

```
grouped = database_df.groupby(['Technology'])

main_df['New column'] = (
grouped.get_group(main_df['Technology']).loc[ 
(grouped.get_group(main_df['Technology']))['Values1'] > main_df['Condition1']) 
& (grouped.get_group(main_df['Technology']))['Values2'] > main_df['Condition2'])]['Character'][0])
```

However, I cannot pass a pd.Series as an argument to the get_group method. I realise I could probably pass `main_df['Technology']` as a str for every entry applying a lambda function, but I would like to perform this operation in a vectorial way... Is there any way?

**MINIMAL VIABLE EXAMPLE:**

```
main_df = pd.DataFrame({'Technology': ['A','A','B'], 
'Condition1': [20, 10, 10], 
'Condition2': [100, 200, 100]})

database_df = pd.DataFrame({'Technology':['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
'Values1':[10, 20, 30, 10, 20, 30], 
'Values2':[100, 200, 300, 100, 200, 300]
'Character':[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]})
```

I would like the outcome of the above mentioned operation with these dfs to be:

```
main_df['New column'] = [3, 3, 2]
```

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Hope that works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If want compare between 2 DataFrames use outer join with convert index to column, then filter by conditions and last filter first matched values:

```
df = main_df.reset_index().merge(database_df,  on='Technology', how='outer')
m = (df['Values1'] > df['Condition1']) & (df['Values2'] > df['Condition2'])

main_df['New column'] = df[m].groupby('index')['Character'].first()
print (main_df)
  Technology  Condition1  Condition2  New column
0          A          20         100           3
1          A          10         200           3
2          B          10         100           2
```

Comment: It definitely works, but I wonder if there is a more efficient way? For very large dfs the first merge seems rather inefficient, especially if ```len(main_df)``` >> ```len(database_df)```, which also leads to a quite inefficient mask calculation (most of the values will be NaN if the ```len()``` condition is true).

Comment: @AdamB. - Yop, agree, but if want filter between 2 different dataframes first is necessary convert them to one, it is possible also in groupby, but is should be slowier.

Comment: I'll go with that if all the possibilities involving groupby are slower! Thanks :)